# Sleep without locking up all of Apache?

Tags: php, locking, delay, sleep

I am new to PHP. I'm making a function for an e-commerce site, that does something when an order is received. However, sometimes the *does something* has to be delayed to wait for a cue. All is well, except for the fact that my code:

```
while(delay reason exists) {
    sleep(120); 
}
```

Seems to lock up the Apache process? Now it gets weird because, in testing, I am triggering this function by hooking a function on an e-commerce page I did not create (WordPress). I then cannot access the website at all from here, but on my phone, it works fine. I can live with this, but I am wondering now what will happen when it gets triggered by a customer placing an order... Will the whole website lock up, because there is no client to inflict it on, or will nothing visibly lock up?

Also, what would happen if the function was called again while still "locked up" in sleep from the last time?

Comment: You shouldn't do this. What if delay reason will exist for forever? Instead, you should rethink your code. What are you waiting for with that sleep? A payment confirmation?

Comment: If you tell PHP to sleep, PHP sleeps.  *Actively*.  And since one PHP request is roughly equal to one Apache process, you get the effect you're seeing.  I would agree with Zoli ... another way is needed to skin this cat, whatever it is.

Comment: Incidentally, it's that particular "request" that's locked up.  That particular user-agent will be waiting and waiting until whatever happens.  Other users should be OK.  That is, until you get five, or ten, or twenty of them doing this exact action and all of 'em waiting.  There's a limit to Apache's ability to handle multiple LONG requests like this.  Another reason to do something else.

Comment: awww. i'm at the end of a long solution hunt. everything works except this. basically, i want to create FileX.txt IF FileX.txt doesnt already exist. if it does exist, we need to wait until it doesnt again (which will always happen within 24 hours, so its okay for resource usage) and then create FileX.txt afterall. only, if user places their order & FIleX exists, its creating this lockup even for them somehow. i could probably get away with it tbh, im sure it will continue if they close the window, and we get payment, and they just return later its all good, but i dont like that... its hacky..